# Why I can`t run my tests using jenkins and gitlab

Tags: java, gradle, jenkins, gitlab

Tests are written in Intellig Idea, the assembly is in Gradle. I pushed it on GitLab. In Jenkins I have created job and specified:
1)Source Code System - git "https://gitlab.com/intro4845827/mysecondproject.git" with credentials - Username and Password, branch - master where pushed my code[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yTX3.png)
2)Steps build - Invoke Gradle script with gradle version and Tasks "apiTests" [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7qtd.png)
3)Allure report
After the build in the console I see that no tests were run. Also in Allure report there is`t tests

```
Started by user Аглиуллин Данил Ильшатович
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace /var/jenkins_home/workspace/firstJob
The recommended git tool is: NONE
using credential be1f608d-8fdc-41be-86e1-7fa18ab93947
 > git rev-parse --resolve-git-dir /var/jenkins_home/workspace/firstJob/.git # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url https://gitlab.com/intro4845827/mysecondproject.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://gitlab.com/intro4845827/mysecondproject.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git --version # 'git version 2.30.2'
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
 > git fetch --tags --force --progress -- https://gitlab.com/intro4845827/mysecondproject.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 12375e2c77a2d445081ca7d47673e8f1a3c08e18 (origin/master)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f 12375e2c77a2d445081ca7d47673e8f1a3c08e18 # timeout=10
Commit message: "Правки по тэгам"
 > git rev-list --no-walk 12375e2c77a2d445081ca7d47673e8f1a3c08e18 # timeout=10
[Gradle] - Launching build.
[firstJob] $ /var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.plugins.gradle.GradleInstallation/Gradle_Jenkins/bin/gradle apiTests
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
> Task :compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :compileTestJava
> Task :processTestResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :testClasses
> Task :apiTests

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 37s
2 actionable tasks: 2 executed
Build step 'Invoke Gradle script' changed build result to SUCCESS
[firstJob] $ /var/jenkins_home/tools/ru.yandex.qatools.allure.jenkins.tools.AllureCommandlineInstallation/Allure_Jenkins/bin/allure generate -c -o /var/jenkins_home/workspace/firstJob/allure-report
allure-results does not exist
Report successfully generated to /var/jenkins_home/workspace/firstJob/allure-report
Allure report was successfully generated.
Creating artifact for the build.
Artifact was added to the build.
Finished: SUCCESS
```

In build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'io.qameta.allure' version '2.9.6'
}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.1'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'

    implementation 'io.qameta.allure:allure-java-commons:2.12.1'
    implementation 'io.qameta.allure:allure-commandline:2.12.1'
    implementation 'io.qameta.allure:allure-rest-assured:2.12.1'
    implementation 'io.qameta.allure:allure-junit5:2.12.1'
    implementation 'io.qameta.allure:allure-assertj:2.12.1'
    implementation 'io.qameta.allure:allure-selenide:2.12.1'
}

def apiTest = tasks.register("apiTests", Test) {
    useJUnitPlatform {
        includeTags "API"
    }
}


test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

In test class:

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Tag;

@Tag("API")
public class MainTest {
    @Test
    public void test1() {
        Assert.assertTrue(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: well - fun fact: your Gradle logs says **the tests have been executed** `> Task :testClasses` so i wonder why your tests did not have failed? is the test source directory part of your build?

Comment: could you please provide more information about the project structure? it could help to identify why wour tests have not been executed....